# Android TV ListView does not return to previously selected item

Tags: android, android-listview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EFla.jpg)I am trying to get ListView returning to the previously selected item. I have a screen split in two parts, where on the left part is a ListView and on the right part is TextView, showing selected text.

Use case: an item is selected and with Dpad right arrow is made move to the TextView, then back with Dpad left arrow to the ListView, move several items down with Dpad arrow down. Then again with Dpad right arrow move to the TextView and left arrow back. The problem is that a different item is selected, not the last one selected, which is not intuitive, moreover it is randomly selected position instead of the position of the last selected item.
Here is listing of my test ListView:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String       LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TextView m_program_description;

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("C-Language", "Java", "Data Structure",
            "Networking", "Operating System", "Compiler Design", "Theory Of Computation",
            "Software Engineering", "Web Engineering"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // simple_list_item_1 is a built in layout. It is part of Android OS, instead of creating our own
        // xml layout we are using built-in layout
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
            view.setSelected(true);
            view.setActivated(true);
        });

        listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onItemSelected() called");
                m_program_description = findViewById(R.id.program_description);
                m_program_description.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                m_program_description.setText(arrayList.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--ListView to store list items-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/program_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="start" >

        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

By behaviour observation (i.e.,without drilling the ListView source code from AOSP website),
I believe you shall store the selected position in an `instance variable` and then reselect the item in `ListView` if it is `not focus` then `focus` again.

---

**In order to store the selected position:**

```
int mItemSelected = -1; // new instance variable
...
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                mItemSelected = position; // store position to mItemSelected
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onItemSelected() called position=" + position);
                TextView m_program_description = findViewById(R.id.program_description);
                m_program_description.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                m_program_description.setText(arrayList.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
            }
        });
```

**In order to re-select the item when focus (With hack, will be explained after the code sample):**

```
        listView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocus) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onFocusChange: isFocus=" + isFocus + ", mItemSelected=" + mItemSelected);

                if (isFocus && mItemSelected != -1) {
                    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ${YOUR_ACTIVITY}.this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                listView.setItemChecked(mItemSelected, true);
                                listView.setSelection(mItemSelected);
                                listView.getChildAt(mItemSelected).requestFocus();
                            });
                        }
                    };

                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0);
                }
            }
        });
```

The related code shall be the three lines using `mItemSelected` as argument. Maybe any of them will work and I am just too lazy to verify it.

The concern here is not about the implementation of selection, it is more about the life cycle of `ListView` when focus has changed.

Originally, I hadn't use a `Timer` to run the code. Same issue was met then. I guess there is a life cycle event which will set the position incorrectly.

**Flow**

1. Focus `ListView`
2. Move to item position X
3. Trigger ListView#setOnItemSelectedListener
4. Set `mItemSelected` to X
5. Press DPad to move to `TextView`
6. Press DPad to move back to `ListView`
7. Trigger ListView#setOnFocusChangeListener
8. `ListView` select item X
9. **Unknown life cycle event moves the item unintentionally**

So after adding a Timer, step 9 and 8 will be swapped and therefore the result will be expected. This is the hacking done here and you can see I even didn't add a delay to the Timer.

If anyone can provide WHY step 9 occurs, please also let me know.

Comment: So this is a way of hacking with ListView. IMO, you shall use RecyclerView which is a descendant of ListView. It provides better functionality, better control and continuous support from Google and community.